# SQL Server Query to get schedules of all power bi refreshes and SSRS subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-tablix

I have a report server with power bi dashboards that have scheduled refreshes, and SSRS reports that have scheduled subscriptions. Is there a sql server query I can implement that gives me the following information:

| Report/Dashboard | Format | Frequency | Time | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blah | Power BI | Daily | 2AM | Daily |
| blah2 | SSRS | Weekly | 8PM | Monday |

I am essentially looking for the schedules of the refreshes and the subscriptions. I have access to the report server database on sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Deirdre for the response, I solved my initial question using this query that I compiled from other queries online.

```
WITH    
        EnhancedSchedule AS
            (
                SELECT s.*
                    ,CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 1 <> 0 THEN 'Sun, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 2 <> 0 THEN 'Mon, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 4 <> 0 THEN 'Tue, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 8 <> 0 THEN 'Wed, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 16 <> 0 THEN 'Thu, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 32 <> 0 THEN 'Fri, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfWeek & 64 <> 0 THEN 'Sat, ' ELSE '' END AS DaysOfWeekString
                    ,CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 1 <> 0 THEN '1st ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 2 <> 0 THEN '2nd, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 4 <> 0 THEN '3rd, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 8 <> 0 THEN '4th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 16 <> 0 THEN '5th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 32 <> 0 THEN '6th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 64 <> 0 THEN '7th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 128 <> 0 THEN '8th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 256 <> 0 THEN '9th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 512 <> 0 THEN '10th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 1024 <> 0 THEN '11th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 2048 <> 0 THEN '12th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 4096 <> 0 THEN '13th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 8192 <> 0 THEN '14th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 16384 <> 0 THEN '15th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 32768 <> 0 THEN '16th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 65536 <> 0 THEN '17th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 131072 <> 0 THEN '18th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 262144 <> 0 THEN '19th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 524288 <> 0 THEN '20th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 1048576 <> 0 THEN '21st, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 2097152 <> 0 THEN '22nd, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 4194304 <> 0 THEN '23rd, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 8388608 <> 0 THEN '24th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 16777216 <> 0 THEN '25th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 33554432 <> 0 THEN '26th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 67108864 <> 0 THEN '27th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 134217728 <> 0 THEN '28th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 268435456 <> 0 THEN '29th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 536870912 <> 0 THEN '30th, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN DaysOfMonth & 1073741824 <> 0 THEN '31st, ' ELSE '' END AS DaysOfMonthString
                    ,CASE WHEN Month = 4095 THEN 'every month'
                    ELSE CASE WHEN Month & 1 <> 0 THEN 'Jan, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN Month & 2 <> 0 THEN 'Feb, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN Month & 4 <> 0 THEN 'Mar, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN Month & 8 <> 0 THEN 'Apr, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN Month & 16 <> 0 THEN 'May, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN Month & 32 <> 0 THEN 'Jun, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN Month & 64 <> 0 THEN 'Jul, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN Month & 128 <> 0 THEN 'Aug, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN Month & 256 <> 0 THEN 'Sep, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN Month & 512 <> 0 THEN 'Oct, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN Month & 1024 <> 0 THEN 'Nov, ' ELSE '' END
                    + CASE WHEN Month & 2048 <> 0 THEN 'Dec, ' ELSE '' END
                    END AS MonthString
                    ,CASE MonthlyWeek
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'first'
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'second'
                        WHEN 3 THEN 'third'
                        WHEN 4 THEN 'fourth'
                        WHEN 5 THEN 'last'
                    END AS MonthlyWeekString
                    ,' starting ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 101)
                    + CASE WHEN EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN ' and ending ' 
                    + CONVERT(VARCHAR, EndDate, 101) ELSE ''
                    END AS StartEndString
                    ,CASE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(HOUR, StartDate) % 12) WHEN 0 THEN '12'
                    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(HOUR, StartDate) % 12)
                    END + ':'
                    + CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, StartDate) < 10 THEN '0'
                    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MINUTE, StartDate))
                    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MINUTE, StartDate)) END
                    + CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, StartDate) >= 12 THEN ' PM' ELSE ' AM'
                    END AS StartTime
                FROM ReportServer.dbo.Schedule s
            ),
        SuperEnhancedSchedule AS
            (
                SELECT EnhancedSchedule.*
                    ,CASE WHEN RecurrenceType = 1
                     THEN 'At ' + StartTime + ' on '
                          + CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 101)
                     WHEN RecurrenceType = 2
                     THEN 'Every ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ( MinutesInterval / 60 ))
                          + ' hour(s) and '
                          + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ( MinutesInterval % 60 ))
                          + ' minute(s), ' + 'starting '
                          + CONVERT (VARCHAR, StartDate, 101) + ' at '
                          + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 8), 0, 6)
                          + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 109),
                                            25, 2)
                          + CASE WHEN EndDate IS NOT NULL
                                 THEN ' and ending '
                                      + CONVERT (VARCHAR, EndDate, 101)
                                 ELSE ''
                            END
                     WHEN RecurrenceType = 3
                     THEN 'At ' + StartTime + ' every '
                          + CASE DaysInterval
                              WHEN 1 THEN 'day, '
                              ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, DaysInterval) + ' days, '
                            END + StartEndString
                     WHEN RecurrenceType = 4
                     THEN 'At ' + StartTime + ' every '
                          + CASE WHEN LEN(DaysOfWeekString) > 1
                                 THEN LEFT(DaysOfWeekString,
                                           LEN(DaysOfWeekString) - 1)
                                 ELSE ''
                            END + ' of every '
                          + CASE WHEN WeeksInterval = 1 THEN ' week,'
                                 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, WeeksInterval)
                                      + ' weeks,'
                            END + StartEndString
                     WHEN RecurrenceType = 5
                     THEN 'At ' + StartTime + ' on day(s) '
                          + CASE WHEN LEN(DaysOfMonthString) > 1
                                 THEN LEFT(DaysOfMonthString,
                                           LEN(DaysOfMonthString) - 1)
                                 ELSE ''
                            END + ' of ' + MonthString + StartEndString
                     WHEN RecurrenceType = 6
                     THEN 'At ' + StartTime + ' on the ' + MonthlyWeekString
                          + ' '
                          + CASE WHEN LEN(DaysOfWeekString) > 1
                                 THEN LEFT(DaysOfWeekString,
                                           LEN(DaysOfWeekString) - 1)
                                 ELSE ''
                            END + ' of ' + MonthString + StartEndString
                     ELSE 'At ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 8), 0,
                                            6) + ' '
                          + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 109), 25, 2)
                          + StartEndString
                END AS ScheduleText
                FROM EnhancedSchedule
            ),
        SubscriptionXML AS
            (
                SELECT s.*
                    ,CONVERT(XML, ExtensionSettings) AS ExtensionSettingsXML
                FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions s
            ),
        Receipients AS
            (
                SELECT SubscriptionXML.*
                    ,ISNULL(Settings.value('(./*:Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1024)'), 'Value') AS SettingName
                    ,Settings.value('(./*:Value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS SettingValue
                FROM 
                    SubscriptionXML
                    CROSS APPLY SubscriptionXML.ExtensionSettingsXML.nodes('//*:ParameterValue') Queries ( Settings )
            )
SELECT c.Path
    ,c.Name AS Report
    ,CASE
        WHEN c.Type = 1 THEN 'Folder'
        WHEN c.Type = 2 THEN 'SSRS Paginated Report'
        WHEN c.Type = 3 THEN 'File'
        WHEN c.Type = 4 THEN 'Linked Report'
        WHEN c.Type = 5 THEN 'Datasource'
        WHEN c.Type = 6 THEN 'Model'
        WHEN c.Type = 8 THEN 'Shared Dataset'
        WHEN c.Type = 9 THEN 'Report Part'
        WHEN c.Type = 11 THEN 'KPI'
        WHEN c.Type = 12 THEN 'SSRS Mobile Report'
        WHEN c.Type = 13 THEN 'Power BI Report'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS Format
    ,CASE
        WHEN ses.RecurrenceType = 1 THEN 'Once'
        WHEN ses.RecurrenceType = 2 THEN 'Hourly'
        WHEN ses.RecurrenceType = 3 THEN 'Daily'
        WHEN ses.RecurrenceType = 4 THEN 'Weekly'
        WHEN ses.RecurrenceType = 5 THEN 'Monthly'
        WHEN ses.RecurrenceType = 6 THEN 'Week of Month'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS Frequency
    ,ses.ScheduleText AS TimeDayFreq
    ,r.SettingName AS ReceipientSettings
    ,r.SettingValue AS Receipients
FROM ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule rs
LEFT JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions s
    ON rs.SubscriptionID = s.SubscriptionID
LEFT JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Catalog c
    ON s.Report_OID = c.ItemID
LEFT JOIN SuperEnhancedSchedule ses
    ON rs.ScheduleID = ses.ScheduleID
LEFT JOIN Receipients r
    ON rs.SubscriptionID = r.SubscriptionID
WHERE c.Type IN (2,13)
    AND s.InactiveFlags = 0
ORDER BY c.Nam
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

This [MSSQLTips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6001/ssrs-reportserver-database-overview-and-queries/) will give you information on how to query SSRS information from the ReportServer database. The equivalent information for Power BI scheduled refreshes can be queried using the [ExecutionLog3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/scheduled-refresh-troubleshoot#executionlog) view. Once you have created the queries you need to pull the information for SSRS & Power BI, you can use UNION ALL to create the table that you want.